# Angularjs: Populating the drop-down as per user input

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I am new to Angularjs. I am trying to do is like this. I have an input field where user inputs a number. Then a dropdown is generated where number of options should be equal to the number entered by the user. Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.addqty = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++) {
      $scope.choices = i;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter quantity: <input type="text" ng-model="qauntity" />
  <button ng-click="addqty()">Add</button>

  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <select>{{choices}}</select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write any javascript function to do this. You can make use of `array.constructor` method and pass the corresponding input number value to implement the functionality.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> Enter quantity:
    <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" />
    <button ng-click="val=quantity">Add</button>
    <div ng-if="val!=undefined">
        <select>
            <option value="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(val) track by $index"> {{$index+1}} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [];
  $scope.quantity = 0;

  $scope.addqty = function() {
    $scope.choices = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++) {
      $scope.choices.push(i)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" />
  <button ng-click="addqty()">Add</button>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        {{choice}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**You have an empty array, then when you click the button an amount of items equal to the quantity that was input is pushed into the array, which in turn is used to populate the select.** I think `type="number"` on the input is more appropriate in this instance, to make sure the user doesn't use text instead of a number.

`$scope.choices = [];` resets the array to empty before starting to populate it again, in case someone clicks the button multiple times.

---

If you want to spice things up a little and make the whole thing a little neater you can add `<div ng-show="choices.length > 0">` around the select-tag. This will ensure that the dropdown is only rendered when there's atleast one item in the array.

**All that's left to do then is make sure you can actually continue working with the selected value:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [];
  $scope.quantity = 0;
  $scope.selected;

  $scope.addqty = function() {
    $scope.choices = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++) {
      $scope.choices.push(i)
      $scope.selected = $scope.choices[0];
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" />
  <button ng-click="addqty()">Add</button>

  <div ng-show="choices.length > 0">
    <select ng-model="selected">
      <option ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        {{choice}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="choices.length > 0">
    <label>Selected value: {{selected}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++)
      $scope.array.push(i + 1);
    $scope.selected = $scope.array[0];
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='number' ng-model='quantity' />
  <input type='button' ng-click='show()' value='Create' />
  </br>
  <select ng-model='selected' ng-options="item for item in array">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of objects in the scope and in your addqty function you can push an object to that array which includes the value and the text you want to the user to see.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choises = [];
  
  $scope.addqty = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++) {
      $scope.choises.push({value:i,text:'text'});
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter quantity: <input type="text" ng-model="quantity" />
  <button ng-click="addqty()">Add</button>


<div ng-show="choises.length > 0">
  <select>
  <option 
    value="{{choise.value}}" 
    ng-repeat="choise in choises">
    {{choise.text}}
  </option>
 </select>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made more better by hiding the New dropdown until no value is assigned:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [];
  $scope.quantity = 0;

  $scope.addqty = function() {
    $scope.choices = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.quantity; i++) {
      $scope.choices.push(i)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" />
  <button ng-click="addqty()">Add</button>

  <div>
    <select ng-show="choices.length">
      <option ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        {{choice}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```